# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict', data = {name: {user_details}}

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I get this error after running a program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "J:#", line 21, in <module>
data = {name: {user_details}}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

So as far as I understood, we cannot use dictionary as a key in a dict "key : value" relationship.

This is the part of the code causing the issue on line 21:

```
data = {name: {user_details}}
```

Could you please explain to me how do I actually fix it. Been on internet a day or so, could not understand =( Thank you in advance bros and sis

Comment: `user_details` is of type dict. So remove `{}` around it and it should work: `data = {name: user_details}`

Answer (score 2):

- Hashable data types: `int`, `float`, `str`, `tuple`, and `NoneType`.
- Unhashable data types: `dict`, `list`, and `set`.

Just use hashable data types as keys